# Subsetting xarray.Dataset with respect to multiple coordinates

Tags: python, subset, python-xarray, netcdf4

Say I have an `xarray.Dataset` object loaded in using `xarray.open_dataset(..., decode_times=False)` that looks like this when printed:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, lat: 15, lon: 34, plev: 8, time: 3650)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) float64 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 ...
  * plev       (plev) float64 1e+05 8.5e+04 7e+04 5e+04 2.5e+04 1e+04 5e+03 ...
  * lat        (lat) float64 40.46 43.25 46.04 48.84 51.63 54.42 57.21 60.0 ...
  * lon        (lon) float64 216.6 219.4 222.2 225.0 227.8 230.6 233.4 236.2 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) float64 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 3.322e+04 ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, bnds) float64 39.07 41.86 41.86 44.65 44.65 47.44 47.44 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, bnds) float64 215.2 218.0 218.0 220.8 220.8 223.6 223.6 ...
    hus        (time, plev, lat, lon) float64 0.006508 0.007438 0.008751 ...
```

What would be the best way to subset this given multiple ranges for `lat`, `lon`, and `time`? I've tried chaining a series of conditions and used `xarray.Dataset.where`, but I get an error saying:

```
IndexError: The indexing operation you are attempting to perform is not valid on netCDF4.Variable object. Try loading your data into memory first by calling .load().
```

I can't load the entire dataset into memory, so what would be the typical way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

NetCDF4 doesn't support all of the multi-dimensional indexing operations supported by NumPy. But does support slicing (which is very fast) and one dimensional indexing (somewhat slower).

Some things to try:

- Index with slices (e.g., `.sel(time=slice(start, end))`) *before* indexing with 1-dimensional arrays. This should offload the array-based indexing from netCDF4 to Dask/NumPy.
- Split up your indexing operations into more intermediate operations that index along fewer dimensions at once. It sounds like you've already tried this one, but maybe it's worth exploring a little more.
- To optimize performance, try different Dask chunking schemes using the `.chunk()`.

If that doesn't work, post a full self-contained example to the xarray issue tracker on GitHub and we can take a look into it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up using `.sel()` (didn't realize it could take slices for some reason). The only issue that I could see coming up is dealing with cylindrical coordinates for longitude. What would you suggest for this? Maybe subsetting longitude using `.where()` after `.sel()`?

Comment: See this answer for a few ideas: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205871/xarray-slicing-across-the-antimeridian

Comment: Ahhhh okay didn't know I could do that with `.sel()` I really need to start reading the source code and docs better. Really great package btw!