# processing copernicus dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray, cdo-climate, cds.copernicus

How can I select a region from xarray dataset with dimensions(time_counter,x,y) with coordinates (time_counter, (nav_lat(x,y) and nav_lon(x,y) as non dimensional coordsinates as float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1021, 1442)).

When I select a latitude/longitude slice it does not work properly, it selects from zero, not from my given slice region. I am unable to save my dataset. Please let me know any solution what can be done. I have taken data from ''https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-oras5?tab=overview''

[i have processed this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9i8f.png)

Comment: This is two questions in one, consider splitting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subsetting xarray.Dataset with respect to multiple coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538021/subsetting-xarray-dataset-with-respect-to-multiple-coordinates)